# "Do you know that they gave their wedding guests love spoons with their initials CARVING on them?" in this sentence 'carving' is right?

Tags: past-participles

"Do you know that they gave their wedding guests love spoons with their initials carving on them?" in this sentence is 'carving' right in grammar?

In this sentence I(non-native speaker) think 'carving' is wrong. Isn't it right 'carved' instead of 'carving'? Their initial can't carve itself so initial should be written in passive voice as 'carved'. Am I wrong?

I and we(my friends) think 'carving' should be changed 'carved'.
I anticipate you native speaker's kind answer.

thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't use the sentence you have problem with as the title of your question. please specify in the title your main question.

Comment: @Ahman yes,you are right. I have changed my question. thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give "a carving" but in that case I would expect the object being handed around to be a carved set of initials.

When the carving is just an embellishment, as here, it should be "with their initials *carved* on them".

Comment: Thanks~! you are right. Someone asked this question to me. I think 'carved is right. but I'm not conviced because I'm not native speaker. So after I read your answer I answered to him 'carved is right' so he says 'this was a test in grammar. but he dind't know the answer. -,-     thanks a lot for your help.